# How to validate different names of checkboxes using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

Could you help me how to validate different names of checkboxes at a time. It means i have a different levels of users. User select at least one Role. How to validate the checkboxes? Here my code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_admin" id="is_admin"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="is_marketing" id="is_marketing"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="is_school_admin" id="is_school_admin"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="is_trainer" id="is_trainer"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="is_coordinator" id="is_coordinator"/>
```

Like this my html Form is there. In this roles user select atleast one role. Please help me how to validate using java script or jquery. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use [:checkbox](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to all checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" class="usertype" name="is_admin" id="is_admin"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="usertype" name="is_marketing" id="is_marketing"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="usertype" name="is_school_admin" id="is_school_admin"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="usertype" name="is_trainer" id="is_trainer"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="usertype" name="is_coordinator" id="is_coordinator"/>
```

then use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select those checkboxes and use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to check whether atleast one of them is checked

```
if(!$('input.usertype').is(':checked')){
    alert('select atleast one user type')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see it loop through all and display the value of checked in a separate output html element. http://jsfiddle.net/Np6aY/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_admin" id="is_admin" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_marketing" id="is_marketing" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_school_admin" id="is_school_admin" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_trainer" id="is_trainer" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_coordinator" id="is_coordinator" />
<input type="button" id="getValButton" value="Get Values">
<div class="checkboxOutput"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#getValButton').on('click', function () {
    var outputText = '';
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index, el) {
        outputText += $(el).attr('name') + ': ' + $(el).is(":checked") + '<br>';
    });
    $('.checkboxOutput').html(outputText);
});
```

Comment: After having seen @Arun P Johny's answer I think I may have misread the question.  Keeping it here for you to decide!